# addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() doesn't read data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listener

In my code below the function setPhoto(url) always receives a null url, but if I call another funtion by clicking a button and it requires the url it receives correctly the data.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);


    reference = mDatabaseAPI.getUserReferenceByUid(user.getUid()).child(PHOTO_URL);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Perfil.this, "La lectura de la foto falló", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    setPhoto(url);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you initializing the url instance anywhere else other than this:

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    }
```

If not, then what is the value of url when you call the function setPhoto(url)? It will be whatever you have initialized url with in this activity. If you initialized with null, it will be null. Why don't you move the setPhoto(url) inside the onDataChange(..) method right after the statement

```
url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

This way, you can be sure that url has a value. The reason url is initialized when a button is clicked is most probably because the ValueEventListener is called with the method onDataChange(...) being invoked. That is why you get the value of url correctly when a button is clicked. Hope this makes it a bit clear.

Answer (score 0):

The call you are making is asynchronous. You need to move `setPhoto(url)` to `onDataChange()`, right after where you do assignment to `url`:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    setPhoto(url);
}
```